Update height of WKWebView
I need help in updating the height of a UITableViewCell based on the WKWebKitView content height.
I have written the code to get the height based on document.body.offsetHeight didn't work as it was adding empty space at the end of webView.
So I used the following method.
extension PDDescriptionCell: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.summaryHeight?.constant = 0

        self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.summaryHeight?.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height

        if let tableView = self.superview as? UITableView {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }

        self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

The issue with this is that the PDDescriptionCell is part of a ProductDetail UITableViewController that has other tableViewCells, and this PDDescriptionCell is on row 3. As soon as I open ProductDetail and scroll to row 3 for PDDescriptionCell, the height is the same as the one set in xib file. However, the tableView is updated. but the correct height is not updated for PDDescriptionCell. If I were to scroll up to row 1 and then back to row 3, the correct height is updated for PDDescriptionCell.
How do I make sure to update the height for row 3 for PDDescriptionCell when row 3 is on the screen itself, with this way of finding the height?
The complete code for PDDescriptionCell:
class PDDescriptionCell: UITableViewCell {
    var product: ProductModel? {
        didSet {
            if let product = product {
                print(product.summary)

                loadContent(product.summary)
            }
        }
    }

    IBOutlet weak var summaryView: WKWebView!
    IBOutlet weak var summaryHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    private let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        print("awake from nib")

        contentView.backgroundColor = .background1

        summaryView.navigationDelegate = self

        let preference = WKWebpagePreferences()

        preference.preferredContentMode = .mobile
        preference.allowsContentJavaScript = true

        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.defaultWebpagePreferences = preference

        if let product = product {
            _ = WKWebViewConfiguration()

            print("HTML string is loaded")

            self.summaryView.loadHTMLString(product.summary, baseURL: nil)
            self.loadContent(product.summary)
        }
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    private func loadContent(_ content: String) {
        let styledHTML = """
    <html>
    <head>
    <style> body { font-size: 30px; /\* Change the font size for the body as needed \*/ font-family: -apple-system; /\* Use the system font \*/ } table { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; } th, td { border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px; font-size: 20px; /\* Change the font size for table cells as needed \*/ } th { background-color: #f2f2f2; } img { width: 100%; /\* Set the width of images to 100% \*/ height: auto; /\* Set the height of images to auto to maintain aspect ratio \*/ margin-bottom: 50px; /\* Add space below each image \*/ } .semibold { font-weight: 600; /\* Set font weight to semibold \*/ } </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = function() { var body = document.body; var html = document.documentElement; var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight); window.webkit.messageHandlers.iOS.postMessage(height); } </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    \(content)
    </body>
    </html>
    """

        // Load the styled HTML content into the WKWebView
        self.summaryView.loadHTMLString(styledHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }
}

extension PDDescriptionCell: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.summaryHeight?.constant = 0

        self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.summaryHeight?.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height

        if let tableView = self.superview as? UITableView {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }

        self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

I have tried getting height using evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState") and evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight"), but it ended up adding empty space at the end of the webview. I'm expecting to use the same code to fetch the height as it works correctly in updating the height but is not updated at a proper time.

If web view solutions did not work try this alternate approach.
Instead of webView, a label with attributed text can be used.

replace the webView with label

replace self.summaryView.loadHTMLString(styledHTML, baseURL: nil) with below
if let data = styledHTML.data(using: .utf8),
   let attributedText = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
    attributedTextLabel.attributedText = attributedText
}




Hello. Apologies for the delayed response. I tried using a label with attributed text to show the text and the images. However, as the product has lots of images in it, the scroll was not smooth when images need to be displayed on the screen. So I moved with webView but encountered this issue. Is there any way to overcome this problem of height not coming up correctly for webView?
